# Automatically import SCSS file for every Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I trying do import globally an variables.scss file

my vue.config.js like the following:

```
module.exports = {
        css: {
            loaderOptions: {
                scss: {
                    additionalData: `@import "@/styles/variables.scss";`
                },
            }
        }
}
```

variables.scss

```
$dark-bg: #1C2537;
```

and vue file where i try use it

```js
<script setup>
// Component logic
</script>

<template>
    <!-- Template -->
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/variables.scss"; // if i add this all works
.left-menu {
  background-color: $dark-bg;
}
</style>
```

when i directly import variables.scss in vue file all work good but global import not works

if any idea what problem is?

i use: "sass": "^1.69.5", "sass-loader": "7.3.1", "vue": "^3.2.26",

i expect my variables from variables.scss works globally in all vue files

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . " an variables.scss file my vue.config.js" - this isn't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've quite similar configuration but the only thing that differs from yours is the `scss` property which is `sass :

Syntax for sass-loader v9 and above :

```js
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
          @use "sass:math";
          @import "@/css/_colors.scss";
          @import "@/css/_animations.scss";
          @import "@/css/_mixins.scss";
        `
      }
    }
```

In my `.vue` file I can do then the following with no errors :

```js
<style lang="scss">
  .message {
    color: $error-color;
  }
</style>
```

Since, according to [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), `sass` options also applies to `scss` options, maybe you could give it a try ?

My declared version of vue / sass and sass-loader in `package.json` :

```json
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0"
```

Important note in documentation : this option is named as `prependData` in sass-loader v8

**EDIT** After digging more since we have some differences in `sass-loader` versions, I found that you should use the `data` option, as suggested by Alex in the comments

See [changelog v8](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2019-08-29) where they say that

> the data option was renamed to the prependData option

And then see [changelog v9](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#900-2020-07-02) where they say that

> the prependData option was removed in favor the additionalData option, see docs

So here is correct syntax for v8 sass-loader (working with scss or sass loaderOptions) :

```js
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@/styles/variables.scss";`
      }
    }
```

For v7 and below :

```js
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        data: `@/styles/variables.scss";`
      }
    }
```

And for v9 and above

```js
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@/styles/variables.scss";`
      }
    }
```

Comment: i tried but not work. can you say which version of  sass, sass-loader and vue you use ?

Comment: It could be an issue with your sass-loader version, try change additionalData to data like this

module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                data: `@import "@/styles/variables.scss";`
            },
        }
    }
};

Comment: I added in my response version I use in my project. Sad to hear it doesn't work (yet)

Comment: I've updated my response since I found the property change from v7 / v8 / v9 in sass-loader changelog. As suggested by Alex, according to your sass-loader option, the good keyword for you is `data` 

Answer (score 2):

You can add the file path to your scss file in your vue.config.js file. Here is an example:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@use "@/assets/scss/variables/variables.scss" as *;`
      },
    },
  },
};
```